# get characters left of cursor until the first space after a symbol is typed

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I am trying to do is build the ability to add tagging with a text editor `@user` and populate a list of users they can select from and it will insert that into the editor. I want to grab all the text before the @ when it is typed up to the first space so that I can distinguish if the user is trying to type an email or wanting to add a tag. I know I can just split up the string from @ and detect that, but I am having a hard time knowing where to start to get that text to begin with.

Any help would be great.

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.element', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 50) {
        //get text here
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Intro

Here is a sample of something that might cover your needs.
However, what I did was indeed of detecting the @, I detected the space.
Once the space was clicked, I went back to find  the @ .

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2uqgorka/35/

### JS

```
  let output = document.getElementById("output");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

input.addEventListener('keyup', logKey);

function logKey(e) {
  
  console.log(e);

  output.innerHTML  += ` ${e.code} + ${e.keyCode}`;
  
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {  //Detect a space
        let startPos = e.target.selectionStart;
        let endPos = e.target.selectionEnd;
        //alert(startPos + ", " + endPos);
        
        if(startPos == endPos){
            console.log("full input:"+e.target.value);
          
          let textUpToPosition =e.target.value.substring(0,endPos-1);
          console.log("textUpToPosition:"+textUpToPosition);
          
            let previousAt = textUpToPosition.lastIndexOf("@");
          let previousSpace = textUpToPosition.lastIndexOf(" ");
          
          console.log("previousAt:"+previousAt);
          console.log("previousSpace:"+previousSpace);
          
          
          if(previousSpace < previousAt){
            let resultText = textUpToPosition.substring((previousAt));
            result.innerHTML = resultText;
          }
          
        }
        
    }
   
}
```

### HTML

```
<textarea id="input">
@Someone test 
</textarea> 

<hr>

KeyStrikes<br>
<div id="output">

</div>

<hr>

Result<br>

<div id="result">

</div>
```